# Possible to update an Exchange o365 Online meeting Location to another room with graphapi or graph explorer

Tags: rest, exchangewebservices, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api, outlook-api

I am able to update the meeting event but does not update location to an actual room on Azure Active directory, only updates to text.

So say someroom is an meeting room.. we only get "someroom" text location.

Is this possible? how

Trying this. Also read maybe I need location.AdditonalData , but see no examples anywhere.

```
    PATCH : Event_URL
Body PAYLOAD :
{
 "subject": "Test Graph 2",
 "location": {
  "displayName": "someroom",
  "locationEmailAddress": "someroom@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
  "address": {
   "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.physicalAddress"
  }
 }
}
```

also tried this:

```
endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events/%7BEVENT_ID%7D


{
 "subject": "Test Graph 2",
 "location": {
  "address": {
   "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.physicalAddress"
  },
  "coordinates": {
   "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.outlookGeoCoordinates"
  },
  "displayName": "room1",
  "locationEmailAddress": "room1@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
  "locationType": "conferenceRoom",
  "uniqueId": "room1",
  "uniqueIdType": "private"
 }
}



enter code here
```

Comment: just noticed something.  We are able to invite a room to meeting , but unlike the normal UI, inviting a room to a meeting with graphapi does not add it as an AD object to the Location field.